# mongodb aggregation sort

Tags: mongodb

I have a database of students and their contact details.
I'm trying to find out the postcode that houses the most students.
The documents for the students look something like this...

> {studentcode: 'smi0001', firstname: 'bob', surname: 'smith', postcode:
>   2001}

I thought I could use the aggregation framework to find out the postcode with the most students by doing something like...

```
db.students.aggregate({$project: { postcode: 1 }, $group: {_id: '$postcode', students: {$sum: 1}}})
```

this works as expected (returns postcodes as `_id` and the number of students in each postcode as 'students', but if I add `$sort` to the pipeline it seems to try sorting by the whole student collection instead of the results of the `$group` operation.

what I'm trying look like...

```
db.students.aggregate({$project: { postcode: 1 }, $group: {_id: '$postcode', students: {$sum: 1}}, $sort: {_id: -1}})
```

but it returns the whole collection and disregards the `$project` and `$group`...
Am I missing something? I thought I'd just be able to sort by descending number of students and return the first item.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You almost had it...

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$group: {_id: '$postcode', students: {$sum: 1}}}, 
  {$sort: {_id: -1}}
);
```

gives (I added some test data matching your sample):

```
{
  "result" : [
    {
        "_id" : 2003,
        "students" : 3
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2002,
        "students" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2001,
        "students" : 2
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

You had an outer `{}` around everything, which was causing some confusion. The group and sort weren't working as separate operations in the pipeline.

You didn't really need the project for this case.

**Update** You probably want to sort by "students", like so, to get the biggest zipcodes (by population) first:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$group: {_id: '$postcode', students: {$sum: 1}}}, 
  {$sort: {students: -1}}
);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the advice. I can't believe it was just a misplaced bracket problem. These are the sort of problems I used to have learning SQL 15 years ago, moving to mongodb has meant leaving behind so much prior knowledge, but I reckon it'll be worth it. Cheers,

Comment: It works for your use case, but this approach doesn't always guarantee the results you expect to see. For example results will be incorrect when you need to group by `field1` but keep it sorted by `field2`.

Comment: I had postcodes POST1, POST2, POST3, each post code have unlike number of students. What should be my sort query to get the sum of each POSTs.

db.test.aggregate(
  {$group: {_id: {'postcodes':'$postcodes'}, students: {$sum: 1}}}, 
  What should be the sort query here.
);

Answer (score 5):

I think your syntax is slightly wrong. Each aggregation operation in the pipeline should be its own document.

```
db.students.aggregate( {$project: ...}, {$group: ...}, {$sort: ...} )
```

In your case, it should be:

```
db.students.aggregate(
    {$project: { postcode: 1 }}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$postcode', students: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$sort: {students: -1}}
)
```

I've tested it on a sample collection based on your schema and it works for me, sorting the grouped post codes by number of students, descending.

Comment: Does `$project` do anything for you in this case?

Comment: @WesFreeman You're right, the $project could be omitted. I guess if you had really large documents, trimming them down to only the necessary information for further processing in the pipeline might be of advantage, but in this case, not much is gained.

Comment: yeah, my 'student' documents actually have a heap more fields, so I'm using project to cut out the unneeded fields.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. my new command is > db.students.aggregate({$project: { postcode: 1 }}, {$group: {_id: '$postcode',
 students: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {students: -1}}) and it works perfectly.