# How to sort date using aggregate from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

How can I sort date by: `ascending` and `descending` order. I already fetched the values from mongodb, but it gives me scrambled order.

**Here is my code to count the distinct values of my date:**

```
router.get('/blooddonationpie', function(req, res) {
Blooddonation.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$date" , count :{$sum:1}}}],function(err, date) {      
      res.json({ success: true, date: date });
      console.log(date);
   });   
});
```

**Gives me an output with no order:**

```
[ { _id: '09-09-2019', count: 3 },
  { _id: '08-09-2019', count: 3 },
  { _id: '07-09-2019', count: 2 },
  { _id: '05-09-2019', count: 8 },
  { _id: '06-09-2019', count: 1 },
  { _id: '10-09-2019', count: 1 },
  { _id: '04-09-2019', count: 4 } ]
```

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451322/mongodb-aggregation-sort

Comment: but i need to know how to sort it in ascending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.find().sort({ property: 1})` for ascending order

`db.collection.find().sort({ property: -1})` for descending order

for more information follow the link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/